# Postfix email alias forwarding

Tags: postfix, forwarding

Currently I have installed, and configured postfix. If I send a email to let's say 'admin@XYZ.com' I receive the email(s) locally on the server. I would like to get these said emails to 'XYZ' to forward to my gmail account. Currently I have tried adding aliases through postfix to no avail.

Current postfix/main.cf

```
# Debian specific: Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name. The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mail.XYZ.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.XYZ.com, XYZ.com, localhost.XYZ.com, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
home_mailbox = mail/
```

Current postfix/virtual

```
admin@XYZ.com gaccount@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an alias map created, you can use that. Simply add the following to it:

```
admin: gaccount@gmail.com
```

Then run the `newaliases` command.

The result should now be that all emails thatshould be delivered to the local account "admin" will be instead forwarded to the specified gmail account.

Comment: Hi Urgoll, after checking the logs it looks to be working but never receive it in my gmail box? LOG: Jul 31 17:21:28 noble postfix/smtp[3965]: 85930501B9: to=<gaccount@gmail.com>, orig_to=<admin@xyz.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c02::1a]:25, delay=0.53, delays=0/0.01/0.07/0.45, dsn=2.0.0, status$
Jul 31 17:21:28 noble postfix/qmgr[3957]: 85930501B9: removed

Comment: Have you checked SPAM folder? [ If messages ACCEPTED by gmail in SMTP session are not delivered at all then report a bug to gmail ]

Comment: Starboy, do a grep of 85930501B9 in your maillog file. Postfix uses a multi-line format, and all lines are required to get the whole picture.